# Equation breaking without Losing alignment

Tags: beamer, equations, amsmath, alignment, split

[image]

I've done this before breaking equation using `\split` while working in `align` environment but this is not the output I want. I want to break the equation but don't want to lose alignment of the equation at equal sign. Ps I'm working in Beamer class, exampleblock.

Below is the code:

```
\begin{frame}{Type Two Error}
\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{Rukhsana Sayed}
\begin{exampleblock}{Example Continued}
\begin{align*}
\alpha &= p(X \in \omega : H_0)\\
\alpha &= p(X = 3, 4, 5 : P \frac{1}{2})\\ 
\alpha &= p(X = 3 / P = \frac{1}{2}) + p(X = 4 / P = \frac{1}{2}) + p(X = 5 / P = \frac{1}{2}) \\
\begin{split} \alpha &= ^5 C_3 \times (\frac{1}{2})^3 \times (\frac{1}{2})^{5 - 3} + ^5 C_4  \times (\frac{1}{2})^4 \times (\frac{1}{2})^{5 - 4} + ^5 C_5 \times (\frac{1}{2})^5 \\ \times (\frac{1}{2})^{5 - 5}
\end{split}
\end{align*}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: you should provide a compete example, but split doesn't lose the alignment, it looks like you are missing a & on the second row of the split

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with a nested `aligned` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Type Two Error}
    \let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{Rukhsana Sayed}
    \begin{exampleblock}{Example Continued}
    \begin{align*}
    \alpha &= p(X \in \omega : H_0)\\
    \alpha &= p(X = 3, 4, 5 : P \frac{1}{2})\\
    \alpha &= p(X = 3 / P = \frac{1}{2}) + p(X = 4 / P = \frac{1}{2}) + p(X = 5 / P = \frac{1}{2}) \\
     \alpha &=\begin{aligned}[t] ^5 C_3 \times (\frac{1}{2})^3 \times (\frac{1}{2})^{5 - 3} + ^5 C_4 \times (\frac{1}{2})^4 \times (\frac{1}{2})^{5 - 4} + {}^5 C_5 \times (\frac{1}{2})^5 \\ \times (\frac{1}{2})^{5 - 5}
     \end{aligned}
    \end{align*}
    \end{exampleblock}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `&` in the continuation line.

I'd split in a different place, though. And remove all `\alpha` symbols except the first one.

I'd also add some vertical space between the rows to better show that the last one is split across two lines.

Finally `^5 C_3` is not really good and should be `{}^5C_3` or the exponent would be attached to the `=` sign or to `+`. I replaced `\frac{1}{2}` with `\tfrac{1}{2}` that gives less prominence to those fractions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\alpha &= p(X \in \omega : H_0)\\[1ex]
       &= p(X = 3, 4, 5 : P = \tfrac{1}{2})\\[1ex]
       &= p(X = 3 / P = \tfrac{1}{2}) 
        + p(X = 4 / P = \tfrac{1}{2})
        + p(X = 5 / P = \tfrac{1}{2}) \\[1ex]
      \begin{split}
       &= {}^5 C_3 \times (\tfrac{1}{2})^3 \times (\tfrac{1}{2})^{5 - 3} + 
          {}^5 C_4  \times (\tfrac{1}{2})^4 \times (\tfrac{1}{2})^{5 - 4} \\
       &\qquad + 
          {}^5 C_5 \times (\tfrac{1}{2})^5 \times (\tfrac{1}{2})^{5 - 5}
      \end{split}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Being in `beamer` is irrelevant.

[image]

Alternatively, use `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\alpha &= p(X \in \omega : H_0)\\[1ex]
       &= p(X = 3, 4, 5 : P = \tfrac{1}{2})\\[1ex]
       &= p(X = 3 / P = \tfrac{1}{2}) 
        + p(X = 4 / P = \tfrac{1}{2})
        + p(X = 5 / P = \tfrac{1}{2}) \\[1ex]
       &=
       \begin{aligned}[t]
       &{}^5 C_3 \times (\tfrac{1}{2})^3 \times (\tfrac{1}{2})^{5 - 3} + 
          {}^5 C_4  \times (\tfrac{1}{2})^4 \times (\tfrac{1}{2})^{5 - 4} \\
       &\quad + 
          {}^5 C_5 \times (\tfrac{1}{2})^5 \times (\tfrac{1}{2})^{5 - 5}
      \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `aligned`, applied to the portion of the line following the `=` is definitely the most reliable method and the easiest to control.

Answer (score 0):

With use of the `multlined` environment defined in `mathtools` package (nested in `align*` environment):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Type Two Error}
    \let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{Rukhsana Sayed}
    \begin{exampleblock}{Example Continued}
    \begin{align*}
    \alpha & = p(X \in \omega : H_0)\\
    \alpha & = p(X = 3, 4, 5 : P \frac{1}{2})\\
    \alpha & = p(X = 3 / P = \frac{1}{2}) + p(X = 4 / P = \frac{1}{2}) + p(X = 5 / P = \frac{1}{2}) \\
    \alpha & = \begin{multlined}[t] 
                ^5 C_3 \times (\frac{1}{2})^3 \times (\frac{1}{2})^{5 - 3} + ^5 C_4
                \times (\frac{1}{2})^4 \times \\
                (\frac{1}{2})^{5 - 4} + {}^5 C_5 \times (\frac{1}{2})^5 \times (\frac{1}{2})^{5 - 5}
               \end{multlined}
    \end{align*}
    \end{exampleblock}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]